# Mean of absolute value of normalized Gaussian Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I have a vector $$x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$, where every entry is sampled form N(0,1).

I further normalize the vector to make its l2 norm 1.
I now want an estimate of mean(abs(X)), which is mean of the absolute values of the entries of X. The purpose of this to compute the scale at which the elements of X are.

I thought that 1/sqrt(n) would be an estimate, but after running simulations, I saw that it was way off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to estimate $$\mathbb E\left[\frac{|x_i|}{\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}}\right]$$ from above? Regardless of the ditribution of samples, if $x_i$ are drawn independently, this value does not increase $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$. Indeed, for $z_i=\frac{|x_i|}{\sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}}$,
$$
\mathbb E z_i^2 = \mathbb E\left[\frac{x_i^2}{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}\right]=\frac1n
$$
since this expectations are the same for $i=1,\ldots,n$ and the sum of these expectations equals to $1$.

Next, $\text{Var}[z_i]=\mathbb E\left[z_i^2\right]-(\mathbb E[z_i])^2\geq 0$  and then 
$$0\leq \mathbb E[z_i]\leq \sqrt{\mathbb E\left[z_i^2\right]}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.$$